# HTML text-align tr

Tags: html, css

Given following simple table structure:

```css
.table tr {
   text-align: center
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Column1</th>
      <th>Column2</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>data</td>
      <td>data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>data</td>
      <td>data</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

It aligns the text of the **th** elements centrally, but not the text of the **td** elements.

But if I e.g. try to change the text-color using the same selector, it gets applied to all table elements (th and td).

I was wondering why that is?

Comment: *"It aligns the text of the th elements centrally"* - Not in the code shown it doesn't.  The `<th>` elements are exactly as wide as the text they contain in this case, so text alignment is a moot point with them.  Perhaps you can update the example to demonstrate what you're asking?

Comment: Thanks. My example was bad, I meant to select the <table> element, not the .table-class. And in my local code, the table had a specific min-width so alignment could be applied in the cells. I now figured out that my confusion came from somewhere else. It had something to do with default alignment-of the th-element (default: centrally aligned) in comparison to the ´td´-element (default: left aligned).

Answer (score 3):

You do not have a class called `table` in your html. Remove the `.` before `table` to select the `<table>`-Element in your HTML.

```css
table tr {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Column1</th>
      <th>Column2</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>data</td>
      <td>data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>data</td>
      <td>data</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Yes, my bad. In my local code the table had a specific class, it was a copy mistake.

Answer (score 0):

The .table refers to a class. You don't have that class on your table. By default th's are center aligned and td's are left aligned.

To apply styles to the table in your question you can just style using
"table tr {
text-align: center
}"

Or add class="table" to your table.